# how to add jquery background image attributes

Tags: jquery

How to add background image attributes to body tag using `jQuery.css()`.

I am trying to change this code:

```
$("body").css("background-image","url('resources/ipad.png')")
```

to somewhat like this :

```
$("body").css("background","#026EB7 url('resources/ipad.png') center top repeat")
```

Can anybody point me in this direction, what could be possible wrong thing?

Comment: Try: `$("body").css("background","url('resources/ipad.png') center top repeat #026EB7")`

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/sLhcD/ are you sure the path to your image is correct? try '/resources/ipad.png' for example :)

Comment: Yes path is correct, although Fresheyeball's (Thanks) solution(given below) works but if i try to club attributes together as above, it doesnot work.

Comment: The order is important.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the below should work:

```
$("body").css("background","url('resources/ipad.png') center top repeat #026EB7 ");
```

but you can always try the alternate jQuery css syntax

```
$('body').css({
     backgroundImage    : 'url("resources/ipad.png")',
     backgroundPosition : 'center top',
     backgroundRepeat   : 'repeat',
     backgroundColor    : '#026EB7'
});
```